# Diminutive bias from minority language code switching?

Tags: reference-request

Code switching satisfies two criteria, which benefit the creation of diminutives.

1. Substrate languages (more generly addstratum) are more likely to be spoken between familiar speakers.
2. They are more likely to be affectionate towards familiars rather than strangers.

The recipient matrix language is the lexicalizer, while the grammar of the donor language is transmitted *robustly* (Blasi *et al.*).

Is there a strong bias in the recipient for rebracketing the unknown suffix as diminutive? In which typology (or topology)?

**Edit:** To address the criticism that the language is not clear, after revisiting the topic while trying to answer myself, I guess a more durected question would be, which kinds of morphemes are particularly likely to become diminutive. And since my experience with diminutives is limited to a few examples of European languages, I'm asking for typological evidence.

For example, shortening *Mich* or *Micky* is hypochoristic from a form of *Michael, Michahel* where *el* is incidently not diminutive, if theophoric *El* "lord" is from Hebrew, though the stereotype of *Deutscher Michel* must be meliorative from Old High-German *michel* "big" (Proto-Germanic **mikilaz*, cp. AGr. *megale*, L. *mega*, Skr. *maha*), and the Hebrew etymology is conventionalized but not well grounded (*mi-cha-el* "who is like god(?)", equivalent to the island dweller from Robin Cruso called *What-day-is-it?* a.k.a. *Venus* "Fri(day)" and the Big Lebowsky character *What year is it?*).

Comment: As far as I am concerned _Is this a strong bias for rebracketing as diminutives?_ is word salad. Is what a bias? What does "a bias for rebracketing" mean? Rebracketing what? And you haven't mentioned diminutives. Moving to close pending clarification.

Comment: In other words, you don't know what "this" is. It's  language, for short. You might have heard of it, literally. Shall I draw you a picture of it? You gotta bring the crayons and I'm sure you got the paper.

Comment: So your question is "Is language a strong bias for rebracketing as diminutives?" Sorry, no it still doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yes, actually. I haven't seen one reasonable motivation of a diminutive suffix and nothing to the opposite, like *John, Jonny Jr., John(?) Sr.* And it's never from a word that could mean small but for example *Caligula*, *-ula* from tool-suffix and the equivalent in German *-(s)el* ([Stöpsel](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/54733/whence-the-s-in-st%c3%b6psel) "stopper, plug; knob, young boy") or frequentativ *-el* (*Stoppeln* "stubble", cp. *prickle, tickle, bristle*, ...)

Comment: Hallelujah! You've actually got to the point of saying what your question is about, and after only two rounds of "this doesn't make any sense". You're asking about the origin of diminutives, and whether they might come from opaque affixes from another language.

Answer (score 0):

If suffixes are regularly added when incorporating foreign words and they enter the matrix language in some derivational process, the suffix has a fair chance of being meaningless in the recipient. And when the donor language is poorly understood (which in turn predicts the use of a second language), it may be difficult to tell the difference synchronically or diachronically. If it is transmitted robustly, however, by education or deduction, it may be unremarkable.

But if not, on the one hand there is a good chance it would equal an existing suffix by accident. This can also happen within a language, when morphemes become homophone because of sound change.

On the other one hand, one would expect a neutral distribution of the suffix about any originly unrelated connotations, unless there is a bias for diminutives, for example, or spatial metaphors, colors, filler words ...

Ideally this needs to be weighted against a bias for diminutives and a favour for eu- or disphemism. As a baseline, a random off-center distribution could become self-resonating for many reasons.

In sum, dimitivues like Lat. *-ulla*, *-ula*, *Caligula* "little boot" are very likely derived from substrates, cp. *kali*, *Achill*, *Kleo*, etc., meaning "boot" is a folk etymology. In the given case, **bol-* "power, might" needs to be reckoned with, inasmuch as the PIE root is not supported in theory and therefore more than likely substratal.

Comment: THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER. To add clarification, edit the question. And yes, now you're actually giving some hint of what you're talking about - even giving an actual example at the end. Quite what it is an example of, I'm not sure. I commented on one of your answers to a question the other day that I felt as if I'd walked in to the last few minutes of a lecture. This is another such example. In the first paragraph, at least you're setting out what you're talking about. But then "it may be difficult to tell the difference". What difference?